# Cannot launch Webcamoid after successful installation

Tags: 16.04

I installed webcamoid by typing in terminal

```
apt update
apt install webcamoid
```

Now when I go to Ubuntu launch icon and type webcamoid the icon appears.

But after clicking on the icon it appears on Ubuntu launcher for a few seconds and then disappear.

Why is it happening so?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

In my case, some dependencies were missing. To confirm you can type webcamoid in terminal:

I got the following output:

> QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
>   qrc:/Webcamoid/share/qml/main.qml:22 module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed
>   qrc:/Webcamoid/share/qml/main.qml:24 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
>   qrc:/Webcamoid/share/qml/main.qml:22 module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed
>   qrc:/Webcamoid/share/qml/main.qml:24 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed

To install the dependencies run:

```
sudo apt install qml-module-qtquick-controls
sudo apt install qml-module-qtquick-dialogs
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I had a similar issue with [Minuet](https://minuet.kde.org/). [Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74213664/4970442) by installing `qml-module-qtquick-controls2` (those on this answer were already installed)